# Django-Rest-Framework can't override serializer unique error_messages

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
class PersonDiscount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('backend.Customer', related_name='discount', on_delete=models.CASCADE, error_messages={
        'unique': _('A discount setting is already set up for this customer.')})
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    discount_auto = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    auto = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

And a following serializer for the model:

```
class PersonDiscountPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonDiscount
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user': {
                'error_messages': {
                    'unique': _('A discount setting is already set up for this customer.')
                }
            }
        }
```

When i tried to create a PersonDiscount instance with existed user from the api i'm not getting the custom error message which i set in both model and serializer.

```
{
  "user": [
    "This field must be unique."
  ]
}
```

I had already looked up in the docs and can't find any other way to understand why the override error_messages not getting applied. I also restarted the django runserver several times already

Hope someone can help me with this problem

Comment: I have had this problem before and i couldn't fix this so i checked uniqueness manually :(

Comment: i looked up and seems like this isn't supported by DRF :( https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3927

Comment: @MojixCoder do you know how to define onetoone field manually in serializer?

Comment: yes i know, but don't do that. you can customize error messages in your `models.py`

Comment: @MojixCoder i customized in my model fields as you can see above, but DRF serializer only validate model field validation at the end of the validation so it get ignored, so it doesnt work. DRF validation for the user field ran first with the default error message(which we can't override right now)

Comment: well if that's not working also, you can check the uniqueness manually, but if you can show custom error message in front-end would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate uniqueness manually as below:

```
class PersonDiscountPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        required=True, 
        queryset=Customer.objects.all(),
    )

    def validate_user(self, value):
        exists = PersonDiscount.objects.filter(user=value).exists()
        if exists:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("err msg")
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = PersonDiscount
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: amazing! this is exactly what i was looking for, i forgot PrimaryKeyRelatedField() exists :)